# How to access properties file form JAR(archive) in Install4j?

Tags: install4j

In my project jar I have config.properties file which includes the installation directory path.Now, while installation if the user changes the installation directory,I need to update the config file with new path selected by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "Modify a ZIP file" action for that purpose. In the "Modification actions" property of the action, add a "Write properties to file" action and make sure that its "Merge into existing file" property and its "Update existing keys" child property are selected. In the "Property definitions" property you can enter key-value pairs like

```
installerDir=The new value
```

Comment: I tried the mentioned steps but property value is still unchanged when I check file in jar after installation is completed. please check the screens for ref -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/joW1S.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ATaS.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP8ju.png

Comment: After PATH_TO_ROOT there should not be a space. Please check the file .install4j/installation.log after the installation, it will show why the action fails.